# How to deal with shared data when throwing exceptions

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, exception, local-variables

When having multiple threads using shared data, how does one correctly handle the destruction of that data when exceptions are thrown?

I'm working on an application where I want one process to be doing work while waiting for a result sent from another process over a network. I implemented a class that creates a thread to wait for the result, something like the following (actual code is too large to post here, so this is a small example):

```
class Notifier {
  public: 
    Notifier(Client* _client) : value(-1), client(_client) {
      listener = boost::thread(&Notifer::Listen, this);
    }

    void Listen() {
      try {
        int rec = client->Receive(); //blocking call to receive data over a socket
        boost::scoped_lock sl(mutex);
        value = rec;
      } catch (...) {
        cout << "Exception thrown in listener" << endl;
      }
    }

    int Get() {
      boost::mutex::scoped_lock sl(mutex);
      return value;
    }

  private:
    int value;
    boost::mutex; 
    boost::thread listener;
    Client* client;
}

int main() {
  Client client; //initialize client, connect, etc.
  Notifier n(client);
  while(n.Get() < 0) {
   // do work
   cout << "Waiting for data" << endl;
   sleep(1);
  }
}
```

This works fine for me until I add exception handling:

```
int main() {
  try {
    Client client; //initialize client, connect, etc.
    Notifier n(client);
    while(n.Get() < 0) {
     // do work
     cout << "Waiting for data" << endl;
     sleep(1);
     throw exception();
    }
  } catch(...) {
    cout << "Exception thrown in main" << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I get the error

> "boost: mutex lock failed in pthread_mutex_lock: Invalid argument".

My guess is that, when the exception gets thrown, the stack for the `main` function gets unwound, destroying the mutex. Then the `Receive()` call in the `Listen` function returns and the `scoped_lock` constructor tries to lock the mutex, which doesn't exist, resulting in the error.

Can someone confirm that this is indeed what is happening? If so, is there a way to communicate to the thread that that the mutex no longer exists or that the thread should terminate? Or is there a more exception-safe way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write a correct destructor for `Notifier` class, which would cancel all blocked calls (i.e. unblock `client->Receive()`) and then terminate `listener` thread. Also you need to modify `Notifier::Listen()` to periodically check for thread termination request... then everything will be Ok.

Comment: That's an interesting idea as long as I can actually cancel the blocked call. My Client class uses the Unix `recv` function, do you know how this can be unblocked?

Comment: Found it - there is a [`shutdown`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shutdown) function. Thanks! I had no idea this was possible.

Comment: I have one more question. If I use the destructor of the Notifier as you suggest, I would be doing e.g. `client->Shutdown()`. But this client is not really "owned" by the Notifier, it's passed in as an argument and in a more complex program it could be used elsewhere after the Notifier has gone out of scope. In this scenario, I don't want to shut down the client. Is there a way to differentiate between a normal destruction and one caused by exceptions so I only shutdown the client in the second scenario?

Comment: I don't understand precisely design of your application (including a "complex" one), but I wonder:
    0) why don't you use boost::asio;
    1) another "problem" for me w/ this design: you have `Notifier` which is coupled tight w/ `Client`;
    2) why not to use completely asynchronous I/O w/ a pool of workers?

Comment: The Client is actually legacy code from a previous programmer, which I am still phasing out. I have a deadline in a few days and won't be able to do it before then, so I'm just trying to work with what I have now. I agree that the Client and Notifier shouldn't be tightly coupled. Could you elaborate more on the pool of workers?

Comment: Consider this approach:
0) `Client` (using `boost::asio`) do completely asynchronous I/O
1) ... yep, you need to start a bunch of threads (running a boost::io_service::run() in a forever loop, handling for thread termination exception)
2) on data arrival `Client` emit a signal (using boost::signals2) w/ signature like `void (const std::string&)`
3) anyone can subscribe to that signal (or any others, like 'IO-failure'), so you just __don't need any special class to notify__

Comment: huh, legacy :(
anyway, you'd better to switch to non-blocking I/O, and asynchronous notifications (from a `Client` class using `boost::signals2`) -- as for me that is the easiest way

Comment: Interesting, this basically combines the signal/slot mechanism to communication over a network. I'm not experienced with boost's signal/slot library but I'll definitely give this a try. Also thank you for the original answer